# How to add cropper.js to a django project

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to follow the guide https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/02/how-to-crop-images-in-a-django-application.html

I'm getting lost when he says `"The jQuery utility to crop images in the Web browser can be downloaded here."`

I can see that you can get to the github from his link. I can then download it from github. Do I put 'jquery-cropper' in the same folder that my manage.py is in and add it to my settings.py's 'INSTALLED_APPS'? If that isn't the case I'm lost. I can't pip install it because it isn't a python package. Thoughts?

Comment: If its a `.js` file, place it in a static folder.

Comment: `jquery-cropper` is a js library. you should treat it as static file, so put it your static directory

Comment: ah, that makes sense. I'm new to everything javascript and so I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

As you've observed, [jquery-cropper](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/jquery-cropper/) is not a Python library, but JavaScript. In Django, JavaScript to be run in the browser is considered a static resource, similar to images and stylesheets. To make it available to web browsers using your site, you'd need to host it as static content.

Django has some solid documentation explaining [how to handle static content in a Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/).

Good luck!